# Visual basic palindrome code

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create an application which will determine whether a string entered by user is a palindrome or not.

Is it possible to do without StrReverse, possibly with for next loop. That's what i have done so far.

Working one, with StrReverse:

```
    Dim userInput As String = Me.txtbx1.Text.Trim.Replace(" ", "")
    Dim toBeComparedWith As String = StrReverse(userInput)

    Select Case String.Compare(userInput, toBeComparedWith, True)

        Case 0
            Me.lbl2.Text = "The following string is a palindrom"
        Case Else
            Me.lbl2.Text = "The following string is not a palindrom"

    End Select
```

Not working one:

```
    Dim input As String = TextBox1.Text.Trim.Replace(" ", "")
    Dim pallindromeChecker As String = input
    Dim output As String

    For counter As Integer = input To pallindromeChecker Step -1

        output = pallindromeChecker

    Next counter

    output = pallindromeChecker

    If output = input Then
        Me.Label1.Text = "output"
    Else
        Me.Label1.Text = "hi"
    End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While using string reversal works, it is suboptimal because you're iterating over the string at least 2 full times (as string reversal creates a copy of a string because strings are immutable in .NET) (plus extra iterations for your `Trim` and `Replace` calls).

However consider the essential properties of a palindrome: the first half of a string is equal to the second half of the string in reverse.

The optimal algorithm for checking a palindrome needs only iterate through half of the input string - by comparing `value[n]` with `value[length-n]` for `n = 0 to length/2`.

In VB.NET:

```
Public Shared Function IsPalindrome(value As String) As Boolean

    ' Input validation.
    If value Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("value")
    value = value.Replace(" ", "") // Note String.Replace(String,String) runs in O(n) time and if replacement is necessary then O(n) space.

    ' Shortcut case if the input string is empty.
    If value.Length = 0 Then Return False ' or True, depends on your preference

    ' Only need to iterate until half of the string length.
    ' Note that integer division results in a truncated value, e.g. (5 / 2 = 2)...
    '... so this ignores the middle character if the string is an odd-number of characters long.
    Dim max As Integer = value.Length - 1
    For i As Integer = 0 To value.Length / 2

        If value(i) <> value(max-i) Then
            ' Shortcut: we can abort on the first mismatched character we encounter, no need to check further.
            Return False
        End If

    Next i

    ' All "opposite" characters are equal, so return True.
    Return True

End Function
```

Comment: Cool algorithm!  Very concise.  A point I had to think through is that this works for odd-numbered strings because the Integer type will truncate the .5 resulting in dividing an odd length by 2, and the extra character in the middle can have any value.

Comment: @BobRodes Correct, that's why it's simpler.

Comment: In VB.Net `3 / 2` is rounded to 2, but integer division `3 \ 2` is truncated to 1. Bit shift also works `length >> 1`

Comment: Perhaps consider simplifying the validation to `If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) Then Throw New ArgumentException(value)`.